# Concept of a Stream Device

Tags: c, linux, shell, stream, operating-system

In my OS class, professor mentions that there are Stream and Storage devices. I mean to ask about Stream devices. I've also heard the terminology [character](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html) devices.

On a Linux VM, the corresponding terminal devices can be seen via the `proc` file system:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ ... ... ... 0 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 10 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 2 -> /dev/tty1
```

It seems that stdin, stdout, stderr all point to the same device, and `zsh` maintains fd `10` for access to the terminal.

I'm wondering specifically about how the terminal works and programs like shell interact with it, since it seems that programs like `cat` only receive input on `<Enter>` when reading stdin. Something curious I found is that you can also write to stdin much like stdout, so I am wondering how the offsets (for coordination between them -- since it seems they share an entry in the open file table) are maintained, since these devices do not have a valid [lseek](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/lseek.html).

Here is an example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
  write(STDIN_FILENO, "hello\n", 6);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is really: what is managing the data you type into your computer and you see on your screen, if it is not "Storage"? I am asking about the concept of a "Stream" device and the above are examples.

I'm also specifically asking about the raw file descriptors and underlying stream device, not the buffered "stream" provided by `FILE*`.

One example is the UNIX `|`, which I understand as having a write offset and read offset, which are updated in a circular (bounded) fashion; however, this is not a standard stream device like stdin or stdout.

Comment: Typically files are block buffered, terminals are line buffered, and other character devices are unbuffered.  See the man page for setbuf.  https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't read too much into it. The separation between block devices and character devices was designed in the 1960s, and now there are more devices. Is a GPU a block or character device? It's not really either one! Driver developers can pick one arbitrarily, based on what they think feels better. (I *think* most devices that are not disks are considered as character devices)

Nonetheless, terminals are classic character devices. So why don't you

Well, the device is the "terminal" device, not the "keyboard" device. If you would connect to the keyboard (now under `/dev/input` and [it's not as simple as just reading the characters](https://thehackerdiary.wordpress.com/2017/04/21/exploring-devinput-1/)) you would see keyboard input the moment you pressed the key.

What's a terminal? It's one of these: [image: VT100 terminal]

Looks like a computer, but it is not a computer. It's just a screen and keyboard that sits on your desk and connects to the one computer in the basement of your building because it's the 1970s and computers are big and expensive.

And depending on what kind of terminal your company bought, it might not send what you typed to the big computer in the basement until you press ENTER. Of course, the computer could send a command to the terminal to change whether this mode was on or off.

And Linux still emulates this system to this day, and that's why we have "virtual terminals" that hold onto what you typed until you press ENTER. There's a whole subsystem of the Linux kernel that makes your screen and keyboard pretend to be a terminal from the 1970s. Alternatively, if you're running a GUI (which you probably are) then you're using a program like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` which also pretends to be a terminal from the 1970s.

That's why Linux doesn't send typed chars to the program until you press enter. It's also the same reason you *can* see what you just typed, as the keys you press go directly to the screen.

If you want to see input immediately, there are a whole lot of terminal modes you can play with, using the functions [`tcgetattr`/`tcsetattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr) or the command [`stty`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty). The thing you're looking for is called "raw" which generally turns off all the special features and just makes it send keypresses straight to your program - see [`cfmakeraw`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr). It would also be wise to memorize the `reset` command (just `reset`, no options) which resets your terminal mode back to the normal one, because the terminal doesn't reset by itself when your program exits, and if you leave it in the wrong mode you could be unable to see what you type, or unable to backspace, or things like that.